# English explanation of Sheva Brachot at a Wedding

Tags: minhag, translation, wedding, sheva-brachos

I was a guest at a wedding recently.  During the sheva brachot under the chuppah in addition to calling up someone to recite the bracha a second person was called up to read a relevant English passage (not a translation nor commentary).

Would there be an issue here?  Assuming the readings were appropriate to a wedding are there any issues which would make this problematic or is this just a matter of custom and/or taste?

Comment: Are you concerned about a hefsek of some sort or just the propriety of introducing new content?

Comment: Igrot Moshe 3:8 forbids adding explanations or translations during blessings and even in between them ("בין הפרקים"). Arguably your case could be different if there is a Minyan listening to the person saying the blessings independent of the person saying the explanations since then the explainer needn't really be considered in the middle of the performance of the Mitzva.

Comment: It is forbidden to pause in the middle of performing a Mitzva the length of time it would take to perform the whole thing (OC 65, 104 etc), so if the explanations take longer than saying all seven blessings straight with no tune at normal pace, then it's definitely a problem. That's probably under 60 seconds in this case (just timed myself).

Comment: Thanks for the comments above.  If its forbidden to be mafsik, etc, then how do we explain the practice of someone announcing who will be making the bracha and giving us their condensed biography?  The problem should be identical and I cant remember the last time i attended an Orthodox or Charedi wedding without it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Answer?

Comment: @TheRiver 1) generally bios are less than 60 seconds and there is 
much more than a minyan, 2) indeed if for some reason you need to split the seven blessings between different people they should all ideally be called up in advance, 3) after the fact, even if there was a complete unambiguous hefsek, the first blessings are still valid and the later ones should still be said.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not doubting your Igrot Moshe citation, which I will try to view. My wedding was performed by a knowledgable Orthodox rav, and he gave an English summary of each bracha after they said it in Hebrew. IY"H, As I am still in contact with him, I'll ask him about this. Apparently, there are other opinions to this.